# How to type commands in Postman?

Tags: user-interface, postman

I feel like I am going insane.  I've been using the Postman application as a GUI to test out APIs.  I have made a Collection scope variable, and I want to remove it.  There is no indication that I can do this through the GUI.  The following should work according to many resources online:

```
pm.collectionVariables.clear();
```

But I have no idea where to type this into the Postman GUI. Every resource assumes that I already know.  How do I open a console that I can toss this command into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's code which is executing Postman's JS API rather than a "command". You can use it in either `Pre-request Script` or `Tests` here:
[image: Tabs]

Read more about scripts [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/).

Also note that'll clear all variables. To delete just one, use:

```javascript
pm.collectionVariables.unset('varName');
```